# Function Returning Itself

Tags: c, function

Is it possible to declare some function type `func_t` which returns that type, `func_t`?

In other words, is it possible for a function to return itself?

```
// func_t is declared as some sort of function pointer
func_t foo(void *arg)
{
  return &foo;
}
```

Or would I have to use `void *` and typecasting?

Comment: @Baratong Imagine implementing a state machine where each state is represented by a function. The function, upon processing the state, returns a function with the new state. This would require declaring a function that returns its own type, something that is AFAIK impossible in C.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes it is possible, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you cannot declare recursive function types in C. Except inside a structure (or an union), it's not possible to declare a recursive type in C.

Now for the `void *` solution, `void *` is only guaranteed to hold pointers to objects and not pointers to functions. Being able to convert function pointers and `void *` is available only as an extension.

Comment: What if he used function forward declaration?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @LewsTherin I don't know how it would help. Any example?

Comment: Isn't `struct x {int a; struct x* next;};` a recursive type?

Comment: @icepack I would think so.. maybe he meant recursive function types

Comment: For what it's worth, in the usual "state machine with function pointer for doing state machine advance" set-up, you can have a function that returns a `struct state_machine` object in which there is a pointer-to-function has type `struct state_machine (*fp)(args)`.  A function `foo` can then "return itself" with: `struct state_machine ret; ret.fp = foo; ... return ret;`

Comment: @icepack Strictly speaking, that's not a recursive type, the `struct x*` in there is a pointer type, that IS different from the `struct x` iteslf, which is prohibited by the standard.

Comment: Note that although C does not require `void*` to be convertible to a pointer to a function, POSIX does—see [`dlsym(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html).

Comment: How about adding that all function pointer types are round-trip convertible?

Comment: What do you call this, then? `void (*the_most_pointless_function_in_the_world(void))(void){ return the_most_pointless_function_in_the_world; }`. What is interesting about this function is that it indeed returns itself, `the_most_pointless_function_in_the_world();` will return the function, which if assigned to a variable, can, itself, be called, but `the_most_pointless_function_in_the_world()();` will turn into a compiler error. I think I pushed C too far...

Comment: @torek A really good answer: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/27vDj3. I thought you always had to use a pointer or reference before the type is fully defined. Apparently not.

Comment: @user877329 C++ class definitions effectively get "compiled" after the entire class has been turned into tokens, so by the time the internal state-processing function is defined, the class *is* defined. The use of `auto` allows us to refer to the class type automatically. You can't do this in C as it does not support this kind of `auto`.

Comment: @torek I thought of line 3. This refers to the incomplete type. I guess it works as long as I do try to instantiate State.

Comment: What @Deduplicator said. You can use any function pointer type as long as you cast back to the right type to call it, because any function pointer can be round-tripped through any other function pointer type.

Answer (score 19):

A possible solution with structs:

```
struct func_wrap
{
    struct func_wrap (*func)(void);
};

struct func_wrap func_test(void)
{
    struct func_wrap self;

    self.func = func_test;
    return self;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Wall` gave no warnings, but I'm not sure if this is 100% portable.

Comment: Compile with -pedantic to warn about using non standard features.

Comment: @Chris compiles with `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c func.c -std=c89` w/o problem.

Comment: This is brilliant, no casting at all, clean types! Should be the preferred answer since this provides not only explanations but a proper solution.
I like the C++-way of passing around function objects (kind of...)!

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast function pointers to `void*` (they can be different sizes), but that's not a problem since we can cast to another function pointer type and cast it back to get the original value.

```
typedef void (*fun2)();
typedef fun2 (*fun1)();

fun2 rec_fun()
{
    puts("Called a function");
    return (fun2)rec_fun;
}

// later in code...
fun1 fp = (fun1)((fun1)rec_fun())();
fp();
```

Output:

```
Called a function
Called a function
Called a function
```

Comment: Casting function pointers to `void *` is an extension: it's *recognised* by the standard as working on almost all real-world compilers, even if the standard doesn't demand it. It is not forbidden or undefined, so "can't" is the wrong word.

Comment: @Leushenko `"even if the standard doesn't demand it"` stop right here: if the C standard doesn't demand something (that is, doesn't define it) the behaviour is undefined, therefore **you can't**. (I checked it - C standard doesn't define conversions from function pointers to data pointers). If converting works in your code, then you aren't writing C - you're writing in its superset (which isn't C)

Comment: @Leushenko To my knowledge, the only guarantee about function pointer conversions in C99 is “A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined” (6.3.2.3:8). Where does the C99 standard “recognise” conversions to `void *`?

Comment: @Leushenko Also, anything that is not defined is undefined: “Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior” (4:2)

Comment: J.5.7: *A pointer to an object or to void may be cast to a pointer to a function, allowing data to be invoked as a function (6.5.4). A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to void, allowing a function to be inspected or modified (for example, by a debugger) (6.5.4).* C99 and C11.

Comment: @Leushenko Look at the section name "Common extensions", also the whole annex J is *informative*, ("Informative data is not a requirement and doesn’t compel compliance." wikipedia). Therefore, no, you still **can't**.

Comment: I suspect that the rational behind not being able to cast a data pointer to a function pointer and back again explicitly in the standard, has to do with the C standard being compatible with different architectures, including Harvard architectures where they belong in different address universes.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Not only do they belong in different universes, but there's no guarantee that pointers to things in one universe will be the same size as pointers to things in the other.  BTW, I would think that a machine 64K code space and 256-byte data space could in most cases use 8-bit code pointers if a compiler and linker built a jump table for each function signature containing all of the functions with that signature whose address was taken.  I'm curious why that isn't normally done even on architectures where a computed jump with a one-byte selector, plus a "full-range" jump, ...

Comment: ...would cost less than a "full range" computed jump.  For example, on the PIC18xx, "movf src,w / call springboardxx / addwf pc / goto xxxx" would cost a total of 7 cycles to jump within a 2MB address space.  Even with the most realistic possible assumptions a 16-bit computed jump would take at least 6, and in most practical implementations it would take more than ten.

Comment: @supercat I am a little rusty on the PIC18, and I am sure you are right, but don't you just set the correct page them jump (is that really 10 cycles?)

Comment: @GradyPlayer: One has to start by performing a CALL so as to put a return address on the stack.  If one has a dedicated routine which us hardwired with the source location of the code pointer can be found, that routine would have to perform two "movff" instructions at two cycles each.  Actually, things could be improved a little for the 8-bit case if the number of locations where a code pointer might be located plus the number of targets total 64 or less.  In that case, the table should consist of a sequence of `movff codePtr,PCL` instructions followed by a series of `goto`.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Doing things that way would reduce to six cycles the cost of an 8-bit pointer dispatch, which is matches the absolute minimum of a 16-bit dispatch.  Since two instruction words and two cycles would be saved off every load/store operation on a code pointer, such a thing would be an unconditional performance win except in cases involving too many different addresses [BTW, the cited design takes advantage of the fact that a "CALL" instruction sets up the upper program-counter bits for the next computed jump]

Answer (score 3):

> In other words, is it possible for a function to return itself?

It depends on what you mean by "itself"; if you mean a pointer to itself then the answer is yes! While it is not possible for a function to return its type a function can return a pointer to itself and this pointer can then be converted to the appropriate type before calling.

The details are explained in the question [comp.lang.c faq: Function that can return a pointer to a function of the same type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472619/comp-lang-c-faq-function-that-can-return-a-pointer-to-a-function-of-the-same-ty)

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39597564/480894) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the function definition

```
T f(void)
{
  return &f;
}
```

`f()` returns a value of type `T`, but the type of the expression `&f` is "pointer to function returning `T`".  It doesn't matter what `T` is, the expression `&f` will always be of a different, *incompatible* type `T (*)(void)`.  Even if `T` is a pointer-to-function type such as `Q (*)(void)`, the expression `&f` will wind up being "pointer-to-function-returning-pointer-to-function", or `Q (*(*)(void))(void)`.

If `T` is an integral type that's large enough to hold a function pointer value *and* conversion from `T (*)(void)` to `T` and back to `T (*)(void)` is meaningful on your platform, you *might* be able to get away with something like

```
T f(void)
{ 
  return (T) &f;
}
```

but I can think of at least a couple of situations where that won't work at all.  And honestly, its utility would be extremely limited compared to using something like a lookup table.

C just wasn't designed to treat functions like any other data item, and pointers to functions aren't interchangeable with pointers to object types.

Comment: If you insist on downvoting, at least tell me *why* so I can fix whatever you think the error is.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
typedef void* (*takesDoubleReturnsVoidPtr)(double);

void* functionB(double d)
{
    printf("here is a function %f",d);
    return NULL;
}

takesDoubleReturnsVoidPtr functionA()
{
    return functionB;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    takesDoubleReturnsVoidPtr func = functionA();
    func(56.7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you could have something return functionA... but you already know the address of that, you just called it.

Comment: the point of being able to return functionA is it may return that or it may return something else, i.e. `if (someCondition) return functionA else return functionB;`

Comment: well In Objective C there is something analogousish `typedef id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...);` since IMP returns an abstract object `id` which can then contain its own `IMP`'s so you could take a object oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void *(*fptr)(int *);
void *start (int *);
void *stop (int *);
void *start (int *a) {
         printf("%s\n", __func__);
         return stop(a);
}
void *stop (int *a) {
         printf("%s\n", __func__);
         return start(a);
}
int main (void) {
         int a = 10;
         fptr f = start;
         f(&a);
         return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a function to return itself by value. However it *is* possible itself to return by a pointer.

C allows to define function types that take undefined number of parameters and those those types are compatible with function types that take defined parameters.

For example:

```
typedef void fun_t();

void foo(int);
fun_t *fun = foo; // types are fine
```

Therefore the following function would work.

```
void fun(void (**ptr)()) {
    *ptr = &fun;
}
```

And below you can find the exemplary usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(void (**ptr)()) {
    puts("fun() called");
    *ptr = &fun;
}

int main() {
    void (*fp)();
    fun(&fp); /* call fun directly */
    fp(&fp);  /* call fun indirectly */
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles in pedantic mode with no warnings for C89 standard.
It produces the expected output:

```
fun() called
fun() called
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a way, you just try this:

```
typedef void *(*FuncPtr)();

void *f() { return f; }

int main() {
    FuncPtr f1 = f();
    FuncPtr f2 = f1();
    FuncPtr f3 = f2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The conversion from `void *` to a function pointer is not standard - and definitely not implicit.

Answer (score -2):

If you were using C++, you could create a `State` object type (presuming the state machine example usage) wherein you declare an `operator()` that returns a `State` object type by reference or pointer.  You can then define each state as a derived class of `State` that returns each appropriate other derived types from its implementation of `operator()`.

Comment: Or if he was using OCaml, the OP could use option -rectypes to get the system to accept the definition `let rec f () = f ;;`, the type of which would be inferred as `unit -> 'a as 'a`. But since he neither tagged the question C++ nor OCaml, we are not really helping, are we?