# Typedef function pointer, for a function that returns a pointer to a function of its own type?

Tags: c

That was a mouthful.  Essentially I have this:

```
typedef int (*decker_function_t)(int);

decker_function_t decker;
// Some logic making decker point to a real function
int i = decker(5);

return 1;
```

However, what I really want is for functions of type `decker_function_t` to return a type of `decker_function_t`, rather than an `int`.  I cannot figure out how to make a typedef self-referential.  Is this possible?

Also please note I am asking strictly for C, not C++,

Comment: Mind if I ask exactly what the use case is here?

Comment: as a hack you could make the function return a void * which can be cast (with a nice macro) back to a decker_function_t. as mentioned in @chux s link, this casting from void * to function pointer is an extension

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536504/function-returning-itself

Comment: Thanks chux.  I swear I did search for this, but sometimes knowing what to search for is half the battle.  Does this mean it isn't possible?

Comment: @Adam S  IMHO, it cannot be done.  Somewhat like trying to be your own parent. :-)

Comment: Honestly I'm a little surprised it can't be done.  Thanks for the answer.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Adam S  Others have answered well.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to declare it directly. The language syntax does not offer the opportunity to break the infinite declarative recursion inherently present in this declaration, which is a pity, since there's no physical recursion in it.

The workarounds would include

1. Using a "generic" function pointer type `void (*)(void)` for the return type. Of course, you will have to cast the returned value to the desired specific function type. This is what is usually suggested as "use `void *`" solution, except that `void *` is not the right way to go about it (formally data pointer types are not interconvertible with function pointer types).
2. Using a wrapper struct type as a middle-man. The language allows referring to struct type from the declaration of the very same struct type in a number of contexts. In a way, that is a supported form of "infinite declarative recursion". By taking advantage of this one can do

   ```
   struct fptr_struct {
     struct fptr_struct (*fptr)(int);
   };
   ```

   and declare such functions as returning `struct fptr_struct` type. This will also require some insignificant syntactic efforts to obtain the returned pointer, i.e. access to the nested `fptr` field, but at least it does not require a cast.

Comment: Formally data pointer types are not *required* to be inter-convertible with function pointer types... but in practicality in i386 and compilers in wide usage they are... but it certainly shouldn't be considered portable C.

Comment: C does not require `void*` to be convertible to a pointer to a function, but POSIX does—see [`dlsym(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html).  Of course, even if you can assume you're only going to run on POSIX-compliant platforms, it's still better to avoid dependencies on non-ISO requirements.

Comment: Regarding #1, is this guaranteed to work by the C language?

Answer (score 1):

Following from the *function returning itself SO*; its possible to return a dummy function pointer which can then be properly cast.

This avoids using a void * and non-standard casting. So it can't return itself,
but is able to return a dummy fp and can be handled by convention:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*dummy_function_type)(int);

typedef dummy_function_type (*decker_function_t)(int);

dummy_function_type some_task(int someparam)
{
  /* do some work.. */
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", __FUNCTION__); //gcc specific
  return 0;
}

dummy_function_type decker_queue_root(int redundantparam)
{
  /* do some work.. */
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", __FUNCTION__); //gcc specific
  return (dummy_function_type)some_task;
}

void process_decker_queue(decker_function_t jobs)
{
  /* nonstandard gcc function nesting follows */
  decker_function_t next_decker(decker_function_t cur_decker, int param)
  {
    if(!cur_decker)return 0;
    return (decker_function_t)(cur_decker(param));
  }

  decker_function_t cursor;
  cursor = jobs;
  while(cursor)
  {
    cursor = next_decker(cursor, 0); //param seems pretty redundant in this context..
  }
}

int main()
{
  //work queue stack
  decker_function_t prime = &decker_queue_root;
  process_decker_queue(prime);
  fprintf(stdout, "this compiles..\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
$ ./test_frecurse 
decker_queue_root
some_task
this compiles..
```

But it would be simpler to just have a list of jobs and call them in order