# Return function pointer to function that returns the same type

Tags: c, function-pointers

In C, how can I declare a function that returns a function that returns a function etc.
I.e., I want something like this

```
typedef A (*A)();
A a = ...
a()()()()();
```

I want to achieve the following C++ behavior:

```
struct A { A operator()() { return A(); } };
A a;
a()()()()();
```

Comment: Seen this before on SO, but unable to find again, but I think the answer is that it is not possible in C.

Comment: @chux How about `typedef int (*f)(int); typedef f (*g)(int); typedef g (*h)(int);` and so on.

Comment: @ajay I misunderstood OP's post. I thought OP wants the function to return a type that is the same as the function.  Perhaps not?

Comment: @chux: that's what I thought too. and I've seen it too.

Comment: As with ajay's example, in C you return pointer to function, not function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536504/function-returning-itself - @Chris, can we mark it as duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate - this has been asked before. Voting to close.

Comment: @mpez0 you can easily return a function(literal fixed sized array containing pure assembly in byte array form that doesn't reference anything that isn't its argument, which may contain function pointers); just create a struct of fixed number of bytes, fill this struct with the compiled bytecode of the function, and return this struct. the function accepting this struct can create a function pointer to the start of this struct, and call it. Would be nicer and more portable if c supported this without needing to manually copy over the bytecode, since we all know it can do it anyway.

Comment: this is guaranteed to work because the functions are returned on the stack as byte arrays inside a struct, and text section has execution enabled. the bytecode is environment independant, since it doesn't reference anything outside of its scope unless its been passed as an argument. c already does this for strings(char *a = ... implicitly compiles the string and places it into a buffer elsewhere on the stack before a pointer is set to this buffer; a code buffer can work the same way, except also be executable).

Answer (score 0):

To have a function return a function of its own type one needs to use a intermediate function type.

As by the C Standard it is allowed to cast a function variable to any other function variable and back the following approach would do:

```
typedef int (*T)(void); /* The type of desire. */
typedef void (*_T)(void);  /* The intermediate type. */

int g(void)
{
  return 42;
}

_T h(void)
{
  return (_T) g;
}

int main(void)
{
  T f = (T) h;
  int a = f();
  int b = ((T) h())();
}
```

`a` and `b` both get `42`assigned.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. You never defined a function that returns itself - `h()` returns a pointer to a function receiving nothing and returning nothing - it does *not* return itself. This is not possible in C, the type system does not allow it. Sure, you can play with pointers and casts to emulate such behaviour, but technically, it's not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a function in `C` -  you return a pointer to a function. If you mean to define a function which returns a pointer to a function which again returns a pointer to a function and so on, then you can use `typedef` to implement it.

```
typedef int (*f)(int);
typedef f (*g)(float);
typedef g (*h)(char);

// and so on
```

However, if you mean to define a function which returns a pointer to a function of its own type, then no you cannot do it because you cannot define a recursive type in `C`. See here for details - [Function Returning Itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536529/1809377)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "almost yes".

Take a look the the answer given by Drew McGowen in response to [Function Returning Itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536504/function-returning-itself/17536529#17536529).

I think that answer presents code that is closest to the behavior you are trying to see.