# comp.lang.c faq: Function that can return a pointer to a function of the same type

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

The following is [Question 1.22](http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html) from the comp.lang.c faq.

Why is the definition of `ptrfuncptr` necessary?

```
typedef int (*funcptr)();     /* generic function pointer */
typedef funcptr (*ptrfuncptr)();  /* ptr to fcn returning g.f.p. */

funcptr start(), stop();
funcptr state1(), state2(), state3();

void statemachine()
{
    ptrfuncptr state = start;

    while(state != stop)
        state = (ptrfuncptr)(*state)();
}

funcptr start()
{
    return (funcptr)state1;
}
```

Comment: A function which returns an `int` is not the same as a function which returns something else (in this case, a pointer to a function). I don't see how `funcptr state = start;` even compiles in the second snippet (it should at least be a warning).

Comment: The second approach from that same FAQ page is better (correct and cleaner).

Comment: @Roland It's just a play around the C type system. The code essentially tries to do what would typically be done in assembly language. Assembly language normally (if ever) does not mandate nor validate types other than primitive numeric types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding the code is [4.13](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html) from the C faq:

> It is guaranteed, however, that all function pointers can be interconverted, as long as they are converted back to an appropriate type before calling

We have a function that returns a pointer to a function of the same type. But since we can't define that directly in C we employ a trick. We just make the function return a generic function pointer and then cast it to the appropriate type. We are allowed to do that because of 4.13 above.

**Why is funcptr a generic pointer? Isn't it a pointer to a function that returns int? Why is that generic?**

According to 4.13 all function pointers can be interconverted so it doesn't really matter how we define it. Just make sure to cast it to the right type before calling it.

**Why is the definition of ptrfuncptr necessary?**

Because that is the type of the `state` functions, they are functions that return a function pointer.

**Shouldn't the code `return (funcptr)state1;` in the function `start()` be `return (ptrfuncptr)state1;`? Because state1 is a pointer to a fuction returning funcptr?**

What start() actually returns is a `ptrfuncptr` but we defined it as a fuction returning `funcptr` therefore we just cast the result to `funcptr`. We cast it to the correct type in the `statemachine`: `state = (ptrfuncptr)(*state)();`

**Why not define all the `state` functions with the right type to begin with instead of doing all the pointer casting?**

Because this would be a recursive definition.

Answer (score 2):

`ptrfuncptr` is intended to serve as a specific pointer type for pointers to various "state" functions, exactly as it is used in the original code. Trying to replace it with `funcptr` would make no sense. The purpose of `funcptr` is to serve as a "generic" pointer. It always has to be cast to proper "specific" function pointer type before use, which is `ptrfuncptr` in this example.

In your version of the code this

```
funcptr state = start;
```

declares `state` as a pointer to function returning an `int`, while in reality `start` returns a function pointer. Formally, this initialization is a constraint violation (aka "will not even compile") because the types are not compatible.

Later you do

```
state = (*state)();
```

which is an attempt to assign an `int` value returned by `(*state)()` to pointer variable `state`, which makes no sense whatsoever and, formally, is also a constraint violation.

And so on and so forth.

If your code compiles, its behavior is still undefined. But again, formally, this should not even compile due to multiple constraint violations. I'm sure your compiler issued quite a few diagnostic messages for your version of the code.

The only reason it can "work" is just a lucky coincidence of how that undefined behavior played out in practice. It preserved pointer information during these conversions (like a 32-bit platform with 32-bit `int` and 32-bit pointers). On a 64-bit platform it has a much smaller chance to "work".

Comment: @Roland: *Any* function pointer type can serve as "generic" function pointer type (in a sense that it preserves pointer information in conversions). Authors of the above code chose `int (*)()`. They could have chosen `double (*)(char)` (breaking your version, BTW) or anything else. But they chose `int (*)()`. They probably just felt that `int` return type looks more "generic" in C.

Comment: @Roland: They cast everything to `funcptr` because they made a design decision - all "state" pointers are passed around as *generic* pointers. So, all interfaces are implemented in terms of `funcptr` and everything is converted to `funcptr` once possible.