# Is it possible to write a c++ std::function that returns itself as a type?

Tags: c++

Let's start with a simple typedef of a function:

```
typedef std::function<uint32_t(SomeStruct *)> HandlerFunction;
```

Here we have a function that returns a uint32_t and takes a pointer to SomeStruct.

What I would like to do is modify this function so it returns a type of itself, something like this:

```
typedef std::function<HandlerFunction(SomeStruct *)> HandlerFunction;
```

Obviously that won't compile, but it represents the end goal I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't that endlessly recursive? My function takes `X` and returns a function that takes `X` and returns a function that takes `X` and returns a function that takes `X`...

Comment: Seems to me you're making this harder than it is.  Depending on what you want to do, [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses) or [function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) are probably appropriate.

Comment: The goal is innocent and simple: A really simple state machine.  The "state" was going to be represented by a function.  Calling the function would return the next "state" which would just be another function.  Maybe it's overly clever.

Comment: @SergeyA - It doesn't have to return itself, it could return a different function that matches the signature.

Comment: This is so similar to a C problem of [function returning itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536504/function-returning-itself).

Comment: This is a duplicate, the referenced question is the exact same question.  I'm not sure why it didn't show up in search.  I used search terms that match the question referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this could be achieved with `std::function`.

However, this code (using a functor instead) compiles and runs in Visual Studio 2017:

```
struct SomeStruct {};

struct Func
{
   Func operator()(SomeStruct*) { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
   Func f;
   Func f2 = f(nullptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible. However, if your goal is to implement a finite state machine [boost::statechart](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html) may help you