# In C is it possible for a function to return a pointer to itself?

Tags: c, function-pointers

**Background**

So this is what happens when you spend a few years writing Haskell then go back to bare metal C code:

**Question**

Is it possible for a function to have as its return type a pointer that is the same typs as the function itself?  Is so, what is the syntax?

Is the name of the function in scope within the function body? or can I get the address of the function that is currently executing?

E.g.

```
void foo() {
  callmeback(&foo); // is this legal
}
```

---

**Why would you want to do this?**

I've got a state machine that handles user input fro some very limited controls which means that the two input operations have to serve several different modes.  I'm refactoring my spaghetti code full of switch statements and globals into something a bit more maintainable.  If I were working in Haskell I would call the current mode function with the user input and have it return the a function to call with the subsequent input -- either itself or the handler for a new mode.  I started to do this in C and realized that I have no clue how to write the type of the handler function.  If this doesn't work out I'll simply set a global variable with the next handler and move on with life, but I just had to ask if it could be done the same way I would in a functional language.

For those that are curious, this is all running on an ESP32, a more capable processor but similar to an what come with and Arduino.

Comment: Dupe; it's cerrtinaly possible to hack it in implementation specific ways if your heart is really set on it, though.

Comment: @CarlNorum Wrong it is 100% OK

Comment: @CarlNorum that answer is unrelated

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/es_irP

Comment: Question title seems mismatched with the body (the title sounds like a duplicate as marked but the body seems to be asking something different).

Comment: You can use an intermediate struct to work around the lack of type self-referenciability (or something like that ;-)) for functions. It's a shame they closed your Q, because the answers to the purported dupe don't look great. An example (pass it to `indent`): `#include <stdio.h>
struct fun {
        struct fun (*fun)(int);
};
struct fun fun(int x){
        struct fun r = {fun};
        printf("%d\n", x);
        return r;
}

int main(void){
        fun(45).fun(32).fun(78);
}`

Comment: Please reword your question's title because from the question's body you don't want to *return* the function's address. Then chances are good that the question will be reopened.

Comment: I think the code you show is definitively possible. Did you try it?

Comment: void functions dont return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to return a [function pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/) to itself in C.

The return type you are looking for is a **void pointer** `void*`

And yes, the name of the function is also visible within its body in C. Things like recursion wouldn't have been possible if this wasn't the case.

*Here is some code for illustration:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* demo() // See the usage of void pointer
{
    printf("This function returns a pointer to itself");
    return &demo;
    // return demo is also fine
    // don't return demo(), that would be recursion!
}

int main()
{
    // Syntax
    void (*demoPtr)() = demo();

    // Test if it worked
    demoPtr(); // There's no problem in ignoring the return value

    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

This function returns a pointer to itself

This function returns a pointer to itself

**Edit:**

After reading the second part of your question which mentions your need to this, I think you may be looking for [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion) or [callback](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callbacks-in-c/). If so then you can clarify it in the comments and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: No! Any odd functionpointer-type will do, but `void*` might not be big enough!

Comment: @Deduplicator In that case you have to deal with the warnings **return from incompatible pointer type** and **initialization from incompatible pointer type**.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a function to have as its return type a pointer that is the same typs as the function itself? Is so, what is the syntax?

This is a requirement to recursively defining a type, and it's not possible, at least in C. Returning the pointer to the function itself is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17536504/11294831).

Like others show, you need some tricks (`void*` or `struct`s) to get it compiled. Standard compliance is not checked there.

> Is the name of the function in scope within the function body?

Yes, of course. Recursion is fine in C.

> […] can I get the address of the function that is currently executing?

Just by the name of the function. This is an example of your scenario:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void caller(void (*callee)(int)) {
  printf("Begin of %s(...)\n", __func__);
  callee(23);
  printf("End of %s(...)\n", __func__);
}

static void to_be_called(int param) {
  printf("Begin of %s(%d)\n", __func__, param);
  if (param == 0) {
    caller(&to_be_called);
  }
  printf("End of %s(%d)\n", __func__, param);
}

int main(void) {
  to_be_called(0);
  return 0;
}
```

---

What you plan is not new in embedded C: Implement a state machine by setting pointers to the current state function. But you will set the next pointer *not by returning* it, but by calling a *setter* function. Some developers even use a global variable for this, *brr*.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can use reference to itself. It is 100% OK.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile int x;

void foo(void (*fptr)())
{
    printf("Iteration: %d Function:%s\n", x++, __FUNCTION__);
    if(x < 10) fptr(foo);
}

void bar(void (*fptr)())
{
    printf("Iteration: %d Function:%s\n", x++, __FUNCTION__);
    if(x < 10) fptr(bar);
}


int main()
{
    bar(foo);
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to cite the relevant parts of the standard.

Comment: @Ayxan same as it is OK to call yourself. There is no difference